# Interaction between Ozone and Carbon Dioxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, water

We are trying to predict what will happen when carbon dioxide gas is introduced into a contact chamber that serves as an ozone contact chamber. These contact chambers presently oxidize compounds found in municipal pool water along with chlorine at below 5 ppm. There are 3 contact chambers (one for each pool) and the temperature range is from 104 to 80 F. We are switching from hydrochloric acid to carbon dioxide to keep the total alkalinity from dropping when the acid is introduced.

Comment: "Predict what will happen" is exceptionally broad. If you can narrow your question to specifics, that will help a great deal. For instance, we don't know what the compounds are in the municipal pool water. See [this link](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for a guide to asking questions here on chemistry.SE.

Comment: Ozone and carbon dioxide will be pretty much indifferent to each other. Indeed, ozone is known for its ability to oxidize almost everything, but $\ce{CO_2}$ is already a final product of oxidation. "What is dead may never die", they say. Likewise, $\ce{CO_2}$ may never be oxidized.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond Todd and Ivan. the other compounds in the municipal pool water would include body oils, salt from perspiration and what ever a particular bather might introduce.

Comment: Again, I would say any reaction between those two is highly unlikely. Both may be short-lived, but for independent reasons.